# Slow page load after Wordpress 4.0.1 update

Tags: wordpress, performance

All my WP sites ran perfectly fast until they got automatically updated to 4.0.1, now they each take approximately 3 minutes to load any page, even in admin. I am using different hostings on those pages, so it's not server related.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCDF2.png

Do you please have any ideas what might be causing the problem or what should I try to do? I tried rolling back to 4.0 but the slowness stays. I'm getting desperate.

Comment: Usual things to try first: disable all plugins and see if that makes a different. The try the TwentyFourteen theme and see what difference that makes. You need to first work out if it's the theme or a plugin that are the issue. Also, turn on debugging to see if it reveals an errors.

Comment: @user3647430 I'm having the exact same issue with one of my websites as well. Luckily I can revert to the previous version more easier as it's using the SVN version of WordPress from github

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, i guess you are using the same template on your all sites. I recommend to change your theme to Twenty Fourteen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I narrowed the issue down to the `options` table of the WordPress database. I'm not entirely sure which rogue option caused the issue after updating to 4.0.1 but something was choking it up pretty badly as every page request was taking 2-3min to load both on front and backend.

I've replaced the options table with a fresh one and the problem was gone. The issue was resolved easily in my case as the website was fairly simple, however, if yours has numerous option values then your only hope it so dissect the table to find what could be choking it.